# Is it possible to convert all regular programming tasks to compile time using meta-programming?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I read about meta-programming, and found it was really interesting. For example, check to see if the number is prime, calculate fibonacci number...I'm curious about its practical usage, if we can convert all runtime solution to meta-programming, the the application would perform much better. Let's say to find max value of an array. We would take O( n ) at run time if it was not sorted. Is it possible to get O( 1 ) with meta-programing?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: C++ meta programing is much like a turning complete source-code generator.

Comment: @Industrial: That's exactly what it is.  But so is a Turing machine.  In other words, that doesn't tell us anything anything useful about what it can be used for in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't because metaprogramming only works for inputs that are known at compile time. So you can have a metafunction that calculates a Fibonacci number given a constant known at compile time:

```
int value = Fibonacci<5>::Value;
```

But it won't work for values that are inputted by a user at runtime:

```
int input = GetUserInput();
int value = Fibonacci<input>::Value; // Does not compile
```

Sure, you can recompile the program every time you get new values, but that becomes impractical for non-trivial programs.

Keep in mind that metaprogramming in C++ is basically a "useful accidental abuse" of the way C++ handles templates. Template metaprogramming was definitely *not* what the C++ standards committee had in mind when creating the C++ standards prior to C++0x. You can only push the compiler so much until you get internal compiler errors (that has changed nowadays with newer compilers, but you still shouldn't go overboard).

There's an (advanced-level) book [dedicated to C++ template metaprogramming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321227255) if you want to see what they are really useful for.

Comment: e.g., business logic based on a relational schema can be dramatically recast with huge amounts of code removed -- but precisely because the inputs are not just well known but completely specified.

Comment: +1 for "metaprogramming is abuse of templates".  Couldn't be put better!

Comment: @Chan: one could build, however, a table giving fibonacci numbers for say, 5, 10, 15, 20 and 25 (for example), and thus speed up subsequent computations :)

Answer (score 5):

If it ain't known when you hit the compile button, then it won't be solvable by meta-programming.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about processing data known at compile-time (as opposed to known at run-time), then theoretically, yes.

In practice, no.  Any non-trivial task quickly becomes a tangled nightmare of impenetrable template code, giving even more impenetrable error messages when they fail to compile. Furthermore, most C++ compilers can only tolerate a certain depth of template nesting before they explode.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Of course, you can't make any system calls, all users will need a compiler to run your program, user input will have to take the form of defining constant expressions, but yeah...if you really, really wanted to you could write just about any program in C++ template code so that it 'runs' during compilation rather than runtime.